# spreadtab \newline in @longtext does not work

Tags: tables, line-breaking, spreadtab

I can't find it in the manual or elsewhere.

How can I make a linebreak like `\\` or `\newline` in [`spreadtab`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab) tables text (`@longtext` sentences) cells?

Edit providing a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \subsection{Zeitaufwand}
     \begin{footnotesize} 
    \begin{center}
      \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{ | l | c | c | c | l | }} \hline
       @ Arbeitspaket   & @ geplant     & @ geleistet   & @ delta   & @ Erklärung \\ \hline     
       @ xy             & 1             & 1             &           & \\ 
       @ zab            & 2             & 8             &  6        & \\     %below i wold like to get a linebreak....
       @ cde            & 8             & 11            &  5        & @ \begin{scriptsize}Some long sentence with no line break.\end{scriptsize}\\      
       \hline \hline         
       @ Total          & sum(b2:b4)    & sum(c2:c4)    & sum(d2:d4) & @ h \\ \hline
        \end{spreadtab}
      \caption{Zeitaufwand}
      \label{tab:Zeitaufwand} 
    \end{center}  
   \end{footnotesize} 
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As you might know from your previous questions, it is easier to help you if you provide the code of a complete document that illustrates your problem. Thanks.

Comment: There is no reference of `@longtext` anywhere in `spreadtab`'s manual – at least not in the current version (v0.4c). Please give us a minimal working example!

Comment: I'm guessing you're refering to the fact that cells with an `@` in them make them text cells in `spreadtab`'s eyes (cf. section 2.3 of the manual)?

Comment: exactly at the point of @ text i can't create a linebreak... hope its posible somehow...

Answer (score 2):

Package `makecell` is your friend here. To get more informations type `texdoc makecell` on your terminal/console.

Because `\subsection` should not be used in `figure` I moved it outside `figure`. To get the `\subsection` before `figure` I added the option `[!hb]` to the environment `figure`. There is no environment `footnotesize`, I changed it to the existing command `\footnotesize`. Environment `center` adds a space, to omit that I used command `\centering`.

Please see the following MWE (important changes are marked with `<========`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{makecell} % <===============================================

\begin{document}

\subsection{Zeitaufwand}
\begin{figure}[!hb] % <===================================
  \footnotesize % <=====================================================
  \centering % <========================================================
  \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{ | l | c | c | c | l | }} \hline
    @ Arbeitspaket   & @ geplant     & @ geleistet   & @ delta   & @ Erklärung \\ \hline     
    @ xy             & 1             & 1             &           & \\ 
    @ zab            & 2             & 8             &  6        & @\makecell{\emph{Some} long sentence with a line break.\\Some long sentence with no line \emph{break}.} \\% <================
    @ cde            & 8             & 11            &  5        & @ \scriptsize Some long sentence with no line break.\\
    \hline \hline         
    @ Total          & sum(b2:b4)    & sum(c2:c4)    & sum(d2:d4) & @ h \\ \hline
  \end{spreadtab}
  \caption{Zeitaufwand}
  \label{tab:Zeitaufwand} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which results in the following pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Command `\makecell{Text\\Text2}` adds two lines `Text` and in the next line `Text2` into the cell without breaking the automatic of calculations in `spreadtab`.

Comment: +1 but `\subsection` should not be used in `figure` and `footnotesize` etc. are not environments.